# thinkpad hdaps with ultrabay hdd

Tags: thinkpad

I'm aware that Thinkpad HDAPS's linux driver can stop the standard hard drive in your computer. However, I have a SSD plugged into my main port and a regular HDD plugged into my ultrabay. Is it possible to wire HDAPS so that it stops the secondary hdd as oppose to the SSD?

I've googled but it seems like no one has done this.